# How to restrict the particular method to be executed once only, When factory and dataprovider annotation method is used?

Tags: java, automation, testng, testng-dataprovider

1. I am automating database automation. I am using @factory and
   @Dataprovider annotation in feed the inputs.
2. I want to restrict this method related alone runs once getCountOfPt1(poiLocId)
3. I tried setting boolean value also, but it fails, because I am using factory as well as dataprovider annotation.
4. The code Which I want to restrict and execute only once is

> ```
> String pt1 = null;
>     if(!alreadyExecuted) {
>     Map<String, Integer> records = DbMr.getCountOfPt1(poiLocId);
>     pt1 = getMaxKey(records);
>     LOG.debug("Max key value is...." + pt1);
>     if (StringUtils.isBlank(pt11)) {
>         records.remove(null);
>         pt1 = getMaxKey(records);
>         alreadyExecuted = true;
>     }
>     }
> ```

**Note:** poiLocId which I passed in this method is from factory method

```
@Factory
public Object[] factoryMethod() {
    Object[] poiLocIdData = null;
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cityName)) {
        List<String> poiLocId = DbMr.getPoiLocId(cityName);

        int size = poiLocId.size();
        poiLocIdData = new Object[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            poiLocIdData[i] = new CollectsTest(poiLocId.get(i));
        }
    } else {
        LOG.error("The parameter is required: Pass City Name");
        Assert.fail("Problems with parameters");
    }

    return poiLocIdData;
}

public CollectTest(String locationId) {
    poiLocId = locationId;
    this.reportsPath = "reports_" + cityName;
    this.extent = new ExtentReports();
}

@DataProvider(name = "pData")
public Object[][] getPData() {
    List<PData> pList = DbMr.getCollectionPs(poiLocId);

    Object[][] testData = new Object[pList.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < poiList.size(); i++) {
        testData[i] = new Object[] { pList.get(i) };
    }
    return testData;
}

@BeforeClass
private void setup() throws Exception {
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportsPath + "/" +
     cityName + "_extent.html");
     htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig("src/test/resources/extent-config.xml");
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "pData")
public void verifyData(PData pData) throws Exception {
    extentTest = extent.createTest(pData.toString());
    String pt1 = null;
    if(!alreadyExecuted) {
    Map<String, Integer> records = DbMr.getCountOfPt1(poiLocId);
    pt1 = getMaxKey(records);
    LOG.debug("Max key value is...." + pt1);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(pt11)) {
        records.remove(null);
        pt1 = getMaxKey(records);
        alreadyExecuted = true;
    }
    }

    if (pt1.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxx")) {
        Assert.assertEquals(pData.getpt1(), "xxxx");

        }
```

Comment: is the variable "alreadyExecuted" a static variable of the class or is it an instance variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Since @factory and @DataProvider work with the instance of the test class, so try to make the "alreadyExecuted" variable as a static variable.(since static variable is at class level")

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine and it runs once only, I have used map to execute only once.

```
// declare it as global variable
private static Map<String, String>LOC_ID_AND_PT1_COUNT_MAP = new HashMap();

//test method
@Test(dataProvider = "pData")
public void verifyData(PData pData) throws Exception {
    extentTest = extent.createTest(pData.toString());
    String pt1 = LOC_ID_AND_PT1_COUNT_MAP.get(LocId);
        if (pt1 == null) {
    Map<String, Integer> records = 
  DbMr.getCountOfPT1(LocId);
            pT1 = getMaxKey(records);
            LOG.debug("Max key value is...." + pt1);
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(pt1)) {
                records.remove(null);
                pt1 = getMaxKey(records);
                LOG.debug("Max key value is...." + pt1);
            }

            LOC_ID_AND_PT1_COUNT_MAP.put(locId, pt1);
        }
```